# Create and access IFrame without 'src' attribute

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe, adblock

there have been so many discussions in regard to access iframe with javascript. however, I can't find anything that related to an iframe without 'src' attribute.

basically, I have an iframe that doesn't have any src/link, it will be created by react and bunch of element will be inserted into this iframe on the page load.

to insert element I am using 'contentDocument!.body' which is the recommended technique.

it works fine in all browsers, except Firefox. apparently, firefox Adblock removing elements from the iframe.

so is it normal behaviour? even though iframe doesn't have an 'src' attribute and created directly in the page, shouldn't be treated as normal dom element?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem!

I have been creating the iframe dynamically with javascript. but look like the iframe must be rendered in the server side, and then it can be referenced and used safely to communicate with the main page